# python and Django export mssql query to excel

Tags: python, sql-server, django, sqlalchemy, django-views

i have build an app in django to extract data from an mssql server and display the results on a table on a template.

what i want to do now is to export the same sql query results to an excel file. I have used pymssql driver to connect to the db and pysqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did, but some how excel file wasn't created when the function was call

```
def download_excel(request):
    if "selectdate" in request.POST:
        if "selectaccount" in request.POST:
            selected_date = request.POST["selectdate"]
            selected_acc = request.POST["selectaccount"]
        if selected_date==selected_date:
            if selected_acc==selected_acc:
                convert=datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
                engine=create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password@servername /db')
                connection = engine.connect()
                metadata=MetaData()
                fund=Table('gltrxdet',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                rate=Table('gltrx_all',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                stmt=select([fund.columns.account_code,fund.columns.description,fund.columns.nat_balance,fund.columns.rate_type_home,rate.columns.date_applied,rate.columns.date_entered,fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num])
                stmt=stmt.where(and_(rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num==fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,fund.columns.account_code==selected_acc,rate.columns.date_entered==convert))

                df = pd.read_sql(stmt,connection)

                writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\excel\export.xls')
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='bar')
                writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

my code actually worked. I thought it was going to save the excel file to 'C:\excel' folder so i was looking for the file in the folder but i couldn't find the excel file. The excel file was actually exported to my django project folder instead.

How to i allow the end user to be able to download the file to their desktop instead of exporting it to the server itself

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it to work with much time spend research. This code will export sql query to excel file which will allow end user to download the excel file

```html
import pandas as pd
from django.http import HttpResponse
try:
    from io import BytesIO as IO # for modern python
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO as IO # for legacy python

def download_excel(request):
    if "selectdate" in request.POST:
        if "selectaccount" in request.POST:
            selected_date = request.POST["selectdate"]
            selected_acc = request.POST["selectaccount"]
        if selected_date==selected_date:
            if selected_acc==selected_acc:
                convert=datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
                engine=create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password@servername /db')

               
                metadata=MetaData(connection)
                fund=Table('gltrxdet',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                rate=Table('gltrx_all',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                      stmt=select([fund.columns.account_code,fund.columns.description,fund.columns.nat_balance,rate.columns.date_applied,fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num])
                stmt=stmt.where(and_(rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num==fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,fund.columns.account_code==selected_acc,rate.columns.date_applied==convert))
                results=connection.execute(stmt)
                
  sio = StringIO()
                df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(results), columns=results.keys())

                ####dowload excel file##########
                excel_file = IO()
                xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
                df.to_excel(xlwriter, 'sheetname')
                xlwriter.save()
                xlwriter.close()
                excel_file.seek(0)

                response = HttpResponse(excel_file.read(), content_type='application/ms-excel vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
                # set the file name in the Content-Disposition header
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.xls'
                return response
```

Comment: The code works and all, but I cant find the exported excel file, any suggestions?